# Jpql one-to-one error in syntax

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I've got a User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private Integer value;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails(this);

    // getters, setters

}
```

UserDetails entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")
class UserDetails {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
         parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    public UserDetails(User user) {
        setUser(user);
    }

    //getters, setters

}
```

And I've got a UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update User set value = ?2 where userDetails.name = ?1")
    Integer addValue(String name, int value);

}
```

Method addValue gives next error:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'set value=1000 where name='John'' at line 1

I tried to move name from UserDetails to User and it worked, but I have to keep it in UserDetails. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing mapping of parent entity with child so just change the mapping to child to parent.

Removed mappedBy from user and add it in UserDetails,
So modified mapping is looks like as below,
i.e.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails(this);

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userDetails")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User user;
```

Comment: I dont think using `"parent"` and '"child"` terms here is correct. There's no inheritance that's taking place.

Comment: @RamanSahasi You can try this thing out and let me know. Read the exception once again.